# How to combine SELECT SQL subquerys with RAND?

Tags: sql, select, join, random, subquery

Hi I'm trying to combine some querys in to one, but I'm unsure how to solve this. I know there are millions of other examples but I can't figure out how to translate them into my query.

This is the database. First is table name:, then Primary Key and Foreign key

```
gallery:
    galleryID
    name
    addedDate

concert:
    concertID
    galleryID
    name
    URL
    addedDate

photo:
    photoID
    concertID
    name
```

Here is my query which is returning NULL on URL on random occasions. I guess this is because concertID and URL should be selected at the same time. But it's not allowed to have `SELECT concertID, URL FROM concert WHERE galleryID = g.galleryID ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` So how do I solve this?

What I'm selecting in this 1st query is correct except from getting NULL on URL. So what I need to select is galleryID AND addedDate FROM gallery (1 galleryID per row NOT 8 of the same), concertID AND URL FROM concert (1 random post with same concertID), name FROM photo (1 random post with same concertID). Giving me these results:

```
11  2012-07-31 15:44:35 90  Picture\Path11  SomePicture28.jpg
36  2012-07-31 14:31:36 208 Picture\Path36  SomePicture11.jpg
09  2012-07-30 15:28:02 33  Picture\Path09  SomePicture69.jpg

SELECT galleryID, addedDate, 
    (SELECT concertID 
        FROM concert 
            WHERE galleryID = g.galleryID 
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS curID, 
    (SELECT URL 
        FROM concert 
            WHERE concertID = curID) AS URL, 
    (SELECT p.name 
            FROM photo p, concert c 
                WHERE p.concertID = curID AND c.galleryID = g.galleryID 
     ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS photoName 
FROM gallery g ORDER BY addedDate DESC LIMIT 8;
```

I have also tried to do this with a JOIN with this error `#1054 - Unknown column 'p.concertID' in 'where clause'`

```
SELECT galleryID, addedDate, c.concertID, c.URL, p.name 
    FROM (SELECT concertID, URL, 
            (SELECT name 
                FROM photo 
                    WHERE p.concertID = curID.concertID 
             ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS photoName 
             FROM concert 
                WHERE c.galleryID = curID.galleryID 
          ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) curID 
LEFT JOIN concert c ON curID.galleryID = c.galleryID 
LEFT JOIN photo p ON p.name = curID.photoName 
ORDER BY addedDate DESC LIMIT 8;
```

Comment: Do you have any concerts with a null url? When you get a null url try to ’select * from concert’ for that concert id just to check it is not null.

Comment: I assume you are using mysql from the syntax.  Is this true?

Comment: No there are no NULL for URL. I think it's because a missmatch of curID from the 2 subquerys that's run similtanius. And yes I'm using mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't see any reason in your SQL why you be getting null for the URL, do they all have a value.

I have redone your query in another format, it is similar to what you already do

```
SELECT R.*, c.URL, (SELECT p.Name FROM Photo p WHERE p.ConcertID = R.CurID ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS PhotoName
FROM 
(SELECT GalleryID, AddedDate,(SELECT ConcertID FROM Concert c WHERE c.GalleryID = g.GalleryID ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS CurID
FROM Gallery g
ORDER BY AddedDate DESC LIMIT 8) AS R
JOIN Concert c ON R.CurID = c.ConcertID
```

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I was going for.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you have a correlated subquery in the "FROM" clause.  And things are getting more confusing from there.

It looks like you are trying to get one photo associated with the concert (which is in a gallery).  You can do this by moving the correlated subquery to the "SELECT" clause:

```
SELECT galleryID, addedDate, c.concertID, c.URL,
       (select name
        from photo p
        where p.concertID = c.concertId
        order by rand()
        limit 1
       ) photoname
FROM concert c left join
      gallery g
      ON g.galleryID = c.galleryID
ORDER BY addedDate DESC
LIMIT 8;
```

To get 8 photos from 8 different galleries, try the following:

```
SELECT galleryID, addedDate, c.concertID, c.URL,
       (select name
        from photo p
        where p.concertID = c.concertId
        order by rand()
        limit 1
       ) photoname
FROM (select g.*
      from gallery g
      order by rand()
      limit 8
     ) g join
     concert c
     ON g.galleryID = c.galleryID
where c.concert_id =
          (select csub.concert_id
           from concert csub
           where csub.galleryID = g.galleryID
           order by rand()
           limit 1
          ) 
ORDER BY addedDate DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but I think I need to explain more. Your query will get me 8 of the latest post's for 1 gallery. But I want 1 random post from 8 different gallery's not just 1.

Comment: If the galleries only need to be probabilistically different, then replace the last "order by AddedDate" with "order by rand()".

Comment: This will give me error: #1051 - Unknown table 'c'. And I also think that select c.* select g.* only can contain one operand?